# Popup window failed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make a login interface,when i click "login" will enter another windows if the information is correct.The Mainwindows and dialog can display alone,but after grouping together,alway popup dialog failed.This problem has troubled me for a long time,if someone can answer for me I would be very grateful and happy,thank you very much.Here is my code：

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bell MT")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Jokerman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 111, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Jokerman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.user_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.user_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 120, 301, 41))
        self.user_name.setObjectName("user_name")
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 180, 301, 41))
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.login = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.login.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 260, 101, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Jokerman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.login.setFont(font)
        self.login.setObjectName("login")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 30, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Jokerman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.login.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "user name:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "password:"))
        self.login.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Market storage"))

    def accept(self):
        if self.user_name.text() == "123" and self.password.text() == "123":
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            dialog = QDialog()
            ui = Ui_Dialog()
            ui.setupUi(dialog)
            dialog.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
        else:
            print("wrong imformation")


class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 480)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-50, 250, 621, 31))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "the second windows"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "popup dialog failed" What happens? Do you get an error? Which?

Comment: No error，just disply  `Process finished with exit code -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly caused because you only have to have a `QApplication`, so when you create another one you get that unexpected behavior. In addition, that task ends quickly so when a `dialog` is a local variable is deleted and therefore the window is also closed, so that it does not happen you must make a `dialog` member of the class.

```
def accept(self):
    if self.user_name.text() == "123" and self.password.text() == "123":
        self.dialog = QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(self.dialog)
        self.dialog.show()
    else:
        print("wrong imformation")
```

Comment: The problem is solved！Thank you for your answer sincerely.I dreamed that someone answered my question last night when I was dreaming.I did not expect it to be true.This is my first question on stack overflow.I deeply feeled the strength and warmth.I’m so grateful for your help and  I think I have fallen in love with stack overflow.hahahahaha~

Comment: @Amy 
If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour] :D

Comment: hahahaha~~  it's very nice of you ,you taught me again，thank you.  :D

Comment: @Amy 
I recommend gaining reputation if you do not want to have limitations, for example help in the revision queue, for more information check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation